# What is the best approach to navigate between pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

Can someone please guide me what is the best way to navigate between pages in below scenario.

e.g : **Home screen -> Login screen -> Profile Screen -> User details screen -> Here user clicks on logout button**

Then user should navigate back to login page by clearing User details and Profile Screen from stack.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

read this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare routes in the main file. From over here you can do

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,"route_name");
```

When user logs out you can use

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('loginPage'))
```

Sample Main File for route naming reference

```
routes: {
    "loginPage": (context) => Login(),
    "signupPage": (context) => SignUp(),
    "profilePage": (context) => ProfilePage(),
  },
  initialRoute: 'loginPage',
```

Comment: Thanks adrsh23 for the answer.  In this way how to pass parameters if needed?

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    "pageName",
    arguments: {'exampleArgument': exampleArgument}
);`

Comment: Here in arguments you need to pass a map

Answer (score 0):

In logout button, use

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```